# PageIndexChanging in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question about pageIndexChanging method.
My code does not enter the pageindexchanging method.
I have add updatePanel ,but it does not  still work.
Do you have any idea?

My code is

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">

        <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:GridView ID="grdEmp" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" EmptyDataText="No records found"
            CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered" RowStyle-CssClass="rowHover" ShowHeader="true" OnRowCommand="grdEmp_RowCommand"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            AllowPaging="True"
             OnPageIndexChanging="grdEmp_PageIndexChanging"
            PageSize="20"

            CellPadding="2" ForeColor="#333333"
            GridLines="None" Width="100%">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />

            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Movie" DataField="name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Director" DataField="director" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Genre" DataField="genre" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Year" DataField="year" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ButtonType="Button" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Like" CommandName="like" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#ffffff" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle CssClass="rowHover" BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333"></RowStyle>
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
            <EmptyDataRowStyle Width="550px" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true"
                HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:GridView>

           </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

---

```
    protected void grdEmp_PageIndexChanging(object sender, 
    GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        grdEmp.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindMoviesGrid();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify UpdateMode to Conditional on Update panel and then specify a triggers section with PostBackTrigger or AsyncPostBackTrigger.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlReg" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>

   </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="grdEmp" />

                </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```